# How do I wait for a UI Loading WebElement to be invisible twice?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I have a **WebElement uiLoader**.
It is basically an ajax call for loading animation that appears on the screen after certian actions.

I have written a function with explicit wait to handle uiLoader like the following,

```
public void handleUILoading(){
    WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocatedBy(uiLoader));
}
```

This works fine except when the **uiLoader** gets visible **twice** one after the other within a second or so. I want the driver to interact with other WebElements only after both the instances of the **uiLoader** become invisible.

Calling the function **handleUILoading()** twice also does not help as it simply executes both the wait statements when the **uiLoader** disappears the first time.

Is there a way I can handle this without using Thread.sleep()?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Awaitility to mock ExplicitWait for conditions beyond those given in ExpectedConditions where you may want to discard exceptions until it's no longer thrown. It also works with ImplicitWait if you choose to use that.

Since you have no guarantee that some event has happened once, twice, or however many times, until you find a condition that strictly satisfies what you're looking for, you're shooting in the dark. Given you say "within a second or so", that's really all you have to work with right now.

You might try something like this:

```
WebElement uiLoader ...
Awaitility.await().atLeast(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
  .ignoreException(ClassOfExceptionThatMayBeThrown.class)
  .until(() -> !uiLoader.isDisplayed());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you

First iteration code just wait for Disappearance of uiLoader and in second Iteration we wait for uiLoader Appearance and Disappearance
or you can remove the if condition if you want to wait for first uiLoader also

```
public void waitForLoaderToAppearAndDisappear(WebDriver driver) {
        By uiLoader = By.xpath("");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

        int loadingBarCount = 0;
        while (loadingBarCount < 2) {
            try {
                if (loadingBarCount == 1) {
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(uiLoader));
                }
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(uiLoader));
                loadingBarCount++;
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // The loading bar did not appear within the timeout
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```